# set Interval function is not working in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, setinterval

The setInterval function is not working in my jsp page, below is my code:-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('form[name="lgform"]').submit(function(evnt){
            evnt.preventDefault();

        try{
            mapPlotVar.clearInterval();
            }
            catch(e)
            {
            }
            mapPlotVar=setInterval($("#btn_login").click(function(){console.log("update");},20000));

        });

        $("#btn_login").click(function(){

             alert("hi");

        });

    });

    </script>


    <body>

    <form name="lgform">
    <div>

    <table id="table"  >
        <tr>

            <td width="35px"><input id="mob"  type="text" name="mob_nu" placeholder="1234567890"  maxlength="10"></td>

            <td width="100px"><input type="button" name="login_btn" id="btn_login" value="Login"></td>

            <td width="100px"><label for="Login" style="color: red" id="login_val"></label></td>

        </tr>

    </table>
    </div>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

After clicking the "btn_login" once i want the function to be called after every 20 seconds so that i get the alert message "hi" after every 20 seconds, but "hi" is only showing once, setInterval function is not working. What is wrong with my code? Any piece of code is appreciated.

I tried to use the set Interval here in a different manner because, i want the function to be called just after my first click and continue after every 20s and it wont work if we put the set interval function inside the function we call on button click in usual way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `setInterval()` takes a function as its first argument.

Comment: Look at your browser console. You have errors!

Comment: But you definitely shouldn't repeatedly attach a click handler in a `setInterval()`.

Comment: @Ishettyl yes i have errors i consloe but not able to figure it out

Comment: @Roamer-1888 i saw those examples, and tried with a function instead of click handler but the function is not calling when i run the program. am a beginner to programming not able to sort it out

Comment: I tried to use the set Interval here in a different manner because, i want the function to be called just after my first click and continue after every 20s and it wont work if we put the set interval function inside the function we call on button click in usual way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a lot of problems. Ignoring the other issues, if you want to set a 20s interval for a function on button click, you need to kick off the interval inside of the click handler.

```
    $("#btn_login").click(function(){

         setInterval( function () {
             alert('hi');
         }, 20000);

    });
```

Of course, this will then happen on every button click. One way to solve it would be to use `.one('click', function() { setInterval...})` instead of `.click()` because it will then work on first click only. But since it looks like you also want to cancel the interval, you'll need to take care of that as well.

edit:

```
    var interval;
    $("#btn_login").one( 'click', function() {
         function run () {alert('hi');}
         run();
         interval = setInterval( run, 20000 );

    });
    // you can now cancel this interval somewhere else
    function someCallback () {
        if ( interval )
            clearInterval(interval);
    }
```

Comment: guess i can cancel the interval using clear interval on another button

Comment: You can, but you also need to save the return value of setInterval, so you can cancel it. There's one answer where this was already done.

Comment: can you share the link of that answer?

Comment: ok, thanks. but i still have a problem that i have to wait 20 s to get the result of my first click. what i actually want is to alert "hi" just after the first click and continue after every 20 seconds. what do you think? That is the reason i tried to use the setInterval in a different manner.

Comment: you can do one call in your click handler and set the other as interval.

Comment: i didnt get that. if you can you give me sample piece of code, it will help me a lot.

Comment: Edited. But in the long run I'd recommend that you pick up a good book. It will save you a lot of time. Practice makes perfect, but the question is - practice of what?

Answer (score 2):

```
setInterval($("#btn_login").click(function(){console.log("update");},20000));
```

The above will call `jQuery.click` once and pass its *return value* (a jQuery object) to `setInterval` but setInterval expects a callable function as its first argument.

The correct way to do it by wrapping into an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function() {
  $("#btn_login").click(function(){console.log("update");})
}, 20000);
```

But this still makes not much sense, since this way a new click event handler will be *added* (but not *executed*) to element every twenty seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There are four basic things wrong with your code:

1. You do everything when the form is submitted, but you have no mechanism to submit the form (and your description says you don't want it to trigger on submission anyway).
2. Your code to tell the browser do stuff when the button is clicked is being passed to `setInterval` instead of the other way around.
3. You aren't passing a function to `setInterval`.
4. The code you want to run every time period is nowhere near your interval code

You need to throw out most of the code and start again.

```
var interval;

function run_on_interval_when_button_is_clicked(){
    alert("hi!");
}

function run_when_button_is_clicked(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    interval = setInterval(
        run_on_interval_when_button_is_clicked,
        20000
    );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_login").on('click', run_when_button_is_clicked);
});
```

None of this has anything to do with JSP. That's server side code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var interval;

$('#btn').on('click',function(){
  
  if(typeof (interval) === 'undefined') {
    
    interval = setInterval(function(){
    alert('hi');
    },20000);
    
    }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#btn_login').on('click', function(){
        setInterval(function(){ console.log("update"); }, 20000);
});
```